# LinkedList null pointer

Tags: java, string, list, nullpointerexception, linked-list

Im trying to get one of the values of one of my objects in a linked list but i recieve a null pointer exception on the following line:

```
txtyourname.setText(model.get(0).getYourname());
```

I know the variable names dont match the context of the application but this is an adaptation of a previous project with the edit dialog option being an additional feature.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Model Class:

```
public class Model {

    private LinkedList<Mat> Mat;
    private String file="amey.xml";
    int recordnum =1;
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Model() {
        Mat = new LinkedList<Mat>();
        boolean readOk = true;
        try{
            XMLDecoder decoder = new XMLDecoder (new FileInputStream(file));
            Mat = (LinkedList<Mat>) decoder.readObject();
            decoder.close();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            //File Not Found
            readOk=false;
        }
        if(!readOk){
            Mat = new LinkedList<Mat>();

        }
        // mats = new Mat[25];
        // numberOfMats = 0;
        initialiseData();
        readTextData();
    }

    public void readTextData(){
        File folder = new File("C:/Users/Adam Worrallo/Desktop/Test Files/");
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
          File file = listOfFiles[i];
          if (file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
            try {
                String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
                String [] data = content.split("\\\\"); //splits into records
                for(int i1=0; i1 < data.length; i1++){
                String [] data2 = data[i1].split("\n"); //splits into lines
                String [] one = data2[0].split(":");
                String [] two = data2[1].split(":");
                String [] three= data2[2].split(":");
                String [] four= data2[3].split(":");
                String [] five= data2[4].split(":");
                String [] six= data2[5].split(":");
                String [] seven= data2[6].split(":");
                String [] eight= data2[7].split(":");
                Mat m = new Mat(one[1].trim(),two[1].trim(),three[1].trim(),four[1].trim(),
                        five[1].trim(),six[1].trim(),seven[1].trim(),eight[1].trim());
                //loop through list and use equals method to check the data isnt already
                //in the list
                    if(Mat.contains(m)){
                        continue;
                    }else{
                        Mat.add(m);
                        recordnum++;
                    }
//              for(int a=0; a <Mat.size(); a++){
//                  if(Mat.get(a).equals(m)){
//                      break;
//                  }else if(a==Mat.size() && !Mat.get(a).equals(m)){
//                      Mat.add(m);
//                      recordnum++;
//                  }
//              }

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            /* do somthing with content */
          } 
        }
    }

    public void readFileData(File f){
          if (f.isFile() && f.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
            try {
                String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(f);
                String [] data = content.split("\\\\"); //splits into records
                for(int i1=0; i1 < data.length; i1++){
                String [] data2 = data[i1].split("\n"); //splits into lines
                //get the users input by splitting it from titles
                String [] one = data2[0].split(":");
                String [] two = data2[1].split(":");
                String [] three= data2[2].split(":");
                String [] four= data2[3].split(":");
                String [] five= data2[4].split(":");
                String [] six= data2[5].split(":");
                String [] seven= data2[6].split(":");
                String [] eight= data2[7].split(":");
                Mat m = new Mat(one[1].trim(),two[1].trim(),three[1].trim(),four[1].trim(),
                        five[1].trim(),six[1].trim(),seven[1].trim(),eight[1].trim());
                    if(Mat.contains(m)){
                        continue;
                    }else{
                        Mat.add(m);
                        recordnum++;
                    }
//              for(int a=0; a <Mat.size(); a++){
//                  if(Mat.get(a).equals(m)){
//                      break;
//                  }else if(a==Mat.size() && !Mat.get(a).equals(m)){
//                      Mat.add(m);
//                      recordnum++;
//                  }
//              }

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            /* do somthing with content */
          } 
        }


    /**
     * @param mat - the object to add
     * @return Starts the add mat command, opening the add mat GUI.
     */

    public boolean addItem(Mat mat) {
        return Mat.add(mat);
    }


/**
 * 
 * @param index - if the index is less than zero it does nothing
 * @return if the index is valid it returns the delete command to the mat class which removes the record.
 */
    public boolean deleteItem(int index) {
        if ((index < 0) || (index >= Mat.size()))
            return false;
        Mat mat;
        mat = Mat.remove(index);
        if (mat == null)
            return false;
        return true;
    }


    /**
     *  
     * @return writes the data to the xml file for storage.
     */
    public boolean savingmats(){
        boolean savedOk=true;
        try{
            XMLEncoder encoder = new XMLEncoder (new FileOutputStream(file));
            encoder.writeObject(Mat);
            encoder.close();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            savedOk=false;
        }
        return savedOk;
    }




/**
 * 
 * @return returns an array containing all mats in the database.
 */
    public Mat[] getAllMats() {
        Mat[] allmats = new Mat[Mat.size()];
        allmats = Mat.toArray(allmats);
        return allmats;

    }


    /**
     * @return sorts the mats alphabetically by their country of origin.
     */
    public void sortbyDate(){
        matDateComparator comp = new matDateComparator();
        Collections.sort(Mat, comp);
    }

    /**
     * @return sorts the mats numerically by their number of layers.
     */
    public void sortbyLocation() {
        matLocationComparator comp = new matLocationComparator();
        Collections.sort(Mat, comp);
    }
//
    /**
     * 
     * @param target
     * @return returns any record with an exhibition location equal to what the user entered.
     */
    public int sequentialSearchForName(String target){
        int index = 0;
        for(Mat m : Mat){
            if (m.getYourname().equalsIgnoreCase(target))
                return index;
            index++;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param target
     * @return returns any record with a country of origin equal to what the user entered.
     */
    public int sequentialSearchforLocation(String target){
        int index = 0;
        for(Mat m : Mat){
            if (m.getLocation().equalsIgnoreCase(target))
                return index;

            index++;
        }
        return -1;

    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param index
     * @return returns the record with the index number requested.
     */
    public Mat get(int index){
        if ((index < 0) || (index >= Mat.size()))
            return null;
        return Mat.get(index);
    }

    private void initialiseData() {
        /**
        Mat first = new Mat("test name", "test depot","24-06-2013","time","location","details",
                "outcome","did");
        addItem(first);

        Mat second = new Mat("adam","Quinton","24-06-2013","time","Quinton","none",
                "nothing happened","nothing");
        addItem(second);
        // TODO Add code here to initially add 2 Mat objects to the array
        // Don't forget to change the value of numberOfMats to 2
        /**
         * Use the following values: Object 1: countryOfOrigin = "Persia" layers
         * = 2 hasWear = false pileDepth = 1.43 material = "rubber" isAbsorbant
         * = true museumZone = "Purple Room" isOnDisplay = true
         * 
         * Object 2: countryOfOrigin = "Russia" layers = 3 hasWear = true
         * pileDepth = 0.66 material = "reeds" isAbsorbant = false museumZone =
         * "Green Room" isOnDisplay = false
         * 
         */
    }

    public int getRecordnum() {
        return recordnum;
    }


}
```

Edit Dialog Class:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public class EditDialog extends javax.swing.JDialog {
        private JPanel mainPanel, inputPanel, controlsPanel, closersPanel;
        private JLabel lblTitle, lblyourname, lblyourdepot, lbldate,lbltime, lbllocation, lbldetails, lbloutcome, lbldid;
        private JTextField txtyourname, txtyourdepot, txtdate, txttime, txtlocation, txtdetails,txtoutcome,txtdid;
        private JButton btnOK, btnCancel;
        private JLabel lblError;
        // labels for spacers
        private JLabel lblNorth, lblEast, lblWest;
        // attribute for holding details
        private Mat mat;
        private Model model;
        private int chosenRecord;

        //this sets out the main window
        public EditDialog(JFrame frame, int index) {
            super(frame);
            // Prevent the user from closing the dialogue
            setDefaultCloseOperation(DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
            setResizable(false);
            setTitle("Add A New Close Call");
            setModal(true);
            setSize(600, 430);
            initGUI();
            setVisible(true);
            chosenRecord = index;
        }

        //this initialises the componenets of the gui
        private void initGUI() {
            mainPanel = new JPanel();
            mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            setContentPane(mainPanel);
            // Inner panels
            inputPanel = new JPanel();
            inputPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            mainPanel.add(inputPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            controlsPanel = new JPanel();
            controlsPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(8,2));
            inputPanel.add(controlsPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            closersPanel = new JPanel();
            mainPanel.add(closersPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            lblTitle = new JLabel("Please Enter The Details For The Close Call");
            mainPanel.add(lblTitle, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            lblTitle.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            lblTitle.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial",1,16));

            // Data entry controls and labels
            lblyourname = new JLabel("Your Name: ");
            lblyourname.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
            controlsPanel.add(lblyourname);
            txtyourname = new JTextField();
            controlsPanel.add(txtyourname);

            lblyourdepot = new JLabel("Your Depot: ");
            lblyourdepot.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
            controlsPanel.add(lblyourdepot);
            txtyourdepot = new JTextField();
            controlsPanel.add(txtyourdepot);

            lbldate = new JLabel("Date Of Incident:");
            lbldate.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
            controlsPanel.add(lbldate);
            txtdate = new JTextField();
            controlsPanel.add(txtdate);

            lbltime = new JLabel("Time Of Incident:");
            lbltime.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
            controlsPanel.add(lbltime);
            txttime = new JTextField();
            controlsPanel.add(txttime);

            lbllocation = new JLabel("Specific Location Of Incident:");
            lbllocation.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
            controlsPanel.add(lbllocation);
            txtlocation = new JTextField();
            controlsPanel.add(txtlocation);

            lbldetails = new JLabel("Incident Details:");
            lbldetails.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
            controlsPanel.add(lbldetails);
            txtdetails = new JTextField();
            controlsPanel.add(txtdetails);

            lbloutcome = new JLabel("Potential Outcome: ");
            lbloutcome.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
            controlsPanel.add(lbloutcome);
            txtoutcome = new JTextField();
            controlsPanel.add(txtoutcome);

            lbldid = new JLabel("What You Did: ");
            lbldid.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
            controlsPanel.add(lbldid);
            txtdid = new JTextField();
            controlsPanel.add(txtdid);

            txtyourname.setText(model.get(0).getYourname());

            // label for error messages
            lblError = new JLabel(" ");
            lblError.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            lblError.setForeground(Color.RED);
            inputPanel.add(lblError, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            // Buttons
            btnOK = new JButton("OK");
            btnOK.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    // validate user input, only close dialogue if OK
                    if(check())
                        setVisible(false);
                }
            });
            closersPanel.add(btnOK);
            btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
            btnCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    mat = null;
                    setVisible(false);
                }
            });
            closersPanel.add(btnCancel);

            // spacers
            lblWest = new JLabel("    ");
            inputPanel.add(lblWest, BorderLayout.WEST);
            lblEast = new JLabel("    ");
            inputPanel.add(lblEast, BorderLayout.EAST);
            lblNorth = new JLabel("    ");
            inputPanel.add(lblNorth, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        }


        public Mat getMat() {
            return mat;
        }

        //this checks that appropriate details have been entered and highlights any errors for the user to see      
        public boolean check() {

            boolean valid = true;
            String name;
            String depot;
            String date;
            String time;
            String location;
            String details;
            String outcome;
            String did;
            // clear any previous error indications
            lblyourname.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            lblyourdepot.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            lbldate.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            lbltime.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            lbllocation.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            lbldetails.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            lbloutcome.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            lbldid.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

            // Check Country Of Origin is not empty
            name = txtyourname.getText();
            if(name.length() < 1){
                // set error condition found
                valid = false;
                // show where error is located
                lblyourname.setForeground(Color.RED);
            }

            depot = txtyourdepot.getText();
            if(depot.length() < 1){
                valid = false;
                lblyourdepot.setForeground(Color.RED);
            }

            date = txtdate.getText();
            if(date.length() < 1){
                valid = false;
                lbldate.setForeground(Color.RED);
            }

            time = txttime.getText();
            if(time.length() < 1){
                valid = false;
                lbltime.setForeground(Color.RED);
            }

            location = txtlocation.getText();
            if(location.length() < 1){
                valid = false;
                lbllocation.setForeground(Color.RED);
            }

            details = txtdetails.getText();
            if(details.length() < 1){
                valid = false;
                lbldetails.setForeground(Color.RED);
            }

            outcome = txtoutcome.getText();
            if(outcome.length() < 1){
                valid = false;
                lbloutcome.setForeground(Color.RED);
            }

            did = txtdid.getText();
            if(did.length() < 1){
                valid = false;
                lbldid.setForeground(Color.RED);
            }

            if(valid){
                  model.get(chosenRecord).setYourname(txtyourname.getText());
                  model.get(chosenRecord).setYourdepot(txtyourdepot.getText());
                  model.get(chosenRecord).setIncidentdate(txtdate.getText());
                  model.get(chosenRecord).setIncidenttime(txttime.getText());
                  model.get(chosenRecord).setLocation(txtlocation.getText());
                  model.get(chosenRecord).setDetails(txtdetails.getText());
                  model.get(chosenRecord).setOutcome(txtoutcome.getText());
                  model.get(chosenRecord).setDid(txtdid.getText());
            }else{
                // error(s) exist so don't try to construct Mat
                mat = null;
                lblError.setText("Errors in input - please correct.");
            }

            return valid;

        }
    }
```

Comment: `model` is `null` at that point. You have to initialize it fist.

Comment: Please post relevant code, a huge code in the post most of the time discourages the SO members.. and as far as NPE is concerned.. please debug and check whether `txtyourname` is null || `model` is null || `model.get(0)` is null

Comment: Try this : http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_02.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private Model model = new Model(); // initialization is MISSING!
```

Your *model* remains *null* when `initGUI();` is invoked from the `EditDialog()` constructor.

Hence, the NPE at

```
txtyourname.setText(model.get(0).getYourname()); // get(0) fails
```

Comment: thanks that worked, sorry for the huge chunk of code but when i try debugging, it would break the second it hit the line so i couldn't see what was null and i wasnt sure what you guys/girls would need.

Comment: Ah, it's okay. But in case you run into something like this again: at the breakpoint you could either `step into` or sometimes `right-click > Inspect` a variable in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You never initialised your model in your Dialog class

```
Model model = new Model();
```

Also, try to make your code [sscce](http://sscce.org/)